# Booting full Linux Mint off USB on Intel Macbook pro?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, osx, usb, uefi

I almost never post questions online but this time I couldn't find a solution to my problem. My problem is that I'm trying to boot full Linux Mint from a USB on a Macbook Pro. I was already successful in live booting and I know about persistent install. But I have a 64 GB flash drive and I want up use it completely for Linux, 4 GBs is not enough. How can I efi boot a full Linux from a fat32 formatted flash drive to be exact. I think I have a decent amount of knowledge about partitioning flash drives and how it differs from hard disks if that helps. I can work on Mac, Windows, or Linux, so I think a solution through on any of those would be great. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!